# Savage 2000W LED Location Lighting Kit

Tags: lighting

I purchased these Savage 2000W LED lights and like them, but the description says that light modifiers can be attached using a Bowens Speedring Adapter. Where can I find this adapter? I have searched everywhere but it seems that every adapter is made for a specific light and I cannot find one for this particular Savage light. I contacted the Savage company but they refuse to reply! So now, I have beauty dishes with no way of attaching to these lights, which really do put out a lot of light. Does anyone know something more about these lights than I do, and can help me resolve my problem?     Thanks!

Comment: ... ah, 2000W equivalent :) Was thinking, 2000W optical output from LED lights would indeed border on the uncivilized....

Answer (score 3):

For a better answer, see if you can find the specific model numbers for both your beauty dishes and lights. I'm assuming you have the "[Savage 2000W Location LED Light Kit](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1110971-REG/savage_led2000k_2000w_location_light_kit.html)" with model number "LED2000K." From what I can tell, these lights already have a built-in Bowens S-type mount. Therefore, any S-mount speedring, such as [this](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1342075-REG/impact_sr_impv2_speed_ring_for_impact.html), should fit.

Note that speedrings are only required for certain types of light modifiers, most often softboxes; some beauty dishes require you to purchase a speedring and others have the mounting portion built in. In the former case, your concern then becomes finding the right Bowens-compatible speedring to fit your brand of *beauty dish*, rather than your lights.